# VNC connection taking a long time to connect (essentially...never)

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vnc, remote-desktop

I have my Ubuntu 13.10 desktop with vnc setup and installed. I'm using both a Macbook's integrated vnc remote desktop program and Windows 7's built-in Remote Desktop program to vnc. Both give the same results.

When I open the Remote Desktop application, I set up the vnc connection. It asks for IP address, username, and password. I plug all those in and click connect. After that, it tries to load,but never stops (I'm guessing, by default, vnc will keep trying to connect until it does). I've literally left it alone for hours, and it still hadn't connected. During this whole process, nowhere does it give me an error....not even a warning about something.

I'm able to ping and SSH into it, but it seems that Ubuntu doesn't like it when I vnc into it.

I don't know what else to say.

I was going off [this source](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ubuntu-remote-desktop-builtin-vnc-compatible-dead-easy/).

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that your DNS is configured incorrectly, and the systems are trying to do a reverse DNS lookup that timeouts.

Try installing [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) to check that the VNC packets get acknowledged, and that there aren't firewall/port blocking issues.

(I had the above issue with SSH before. Setting `UseDNS=no` cut 4-5 seconds off of the total login time. And I couldn't just fix the DNS records because it was a home router that didn't support it.)

Answer (score 2):

The thing that strikes me is the term "When I open the Remote Desktop application", Microsoft's Remote Desktop client (mstsc.exe) is not the same protocol as VNC. (espcially when you describe it terms of "host/username/password" - most VNC clients ask for only a IP address, and will prompt for a password on connection). This would explain the timeout (as RDP will be connecting to port 3389 and not VNC's default port of 5900).

I think the confusion is probably caused by Apple referring to the tool as "Enable Remote Desktop", which technically it is a remotely accessible desktop - but it uses VNC and not RDP as the underlying protocol.

To connect to a VNC server you need a VNC client (such as [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/download.php) or [RealVNC](https://www.realvnc.com/download/) which both have freely available downloads).